# ¿Cómo escribir caracteres griegos en archivo desde Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Recientemente estaba programando desde Python una plantilla donde la mayoría del texto es griego. El `print()` no da ningún problema, pero al tratar de guardar la plantilla en un documento de texto (independientemente del formato) con los datos introducidos por el usuario –que incluye el cuerpo de texto en griego– salta el siguiente error:

```
File "C:\Users\Anmova\Python\artgriego.py", line 79, in <module>
  prueba.write(artcomp)
File "C:\Users\Anmova\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
  return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
  UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 9-16: character maps to <undefined>
```

El código utilizado es el siguiente:

```
print('artcomp')
with open('prueba.txt', 'w') as prueba:
    prueba.write(artcomp)
```

`artcomp` es la plantilla en griego con los datos introducidos desde la consola.

He probado a hacerlo con caracteres latinos y no he tenido ningún problema. ¿Cómo podría pasarse la plantilla a un archivo nuevo que contenga caracteres griegos?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido/a a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio. También, a leer [ask].  Sugiero que edites tu pregunta e incluyas el código con el que guardas el archivo. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que estás abriendo el archivo utilizando una codificación que no soporta los caracteres griegos.

Mi recomendación es que abras el archivo utilizando codificación Unicode, específicamente `UTF-8`, de manera que los caracteres griegos estén soportados.

Esto lo logras así:

```
with open('prueba.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as prueba:
```

Ya con eso, no debiera darte problema.

Un saludo.